# Swift: using combination of Combine and async/await results in Fatal error: SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE tried to resume its continuation

Tags: swift, async-await, combine, continuations

I am trying to learn Combine and understand how I can make it work with the new async/await syntax. I have this code which consists of a view controller with a button and a table view, the button triggers a request to MapKit's `MKLocalSearchCompleter` with a random text, which then publishes the update to reload the view controller's table view, with the data fetched from the `MKLocalSearchCompleter`.

For some reason, the second time that I tap the button and `withCheckedContinuation` gets called again, I get this error:

> Fatal error: SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: fillTableView(with:) tried to resume its continuation more than once, returning ["Recklinghausen", "Recquignies", "Recloses", "Recco", "Recy", "Reconvilier", "Rectorat de Paris", "Recke", "Recques-sur-Course", "Recto Versoi", "Rechberghausen", "Rechlin", "Reclinghem", "Reckange-sur-Mess", "Récourt"]!

I don't understand because I though that the continuation was correctly resuming after the first call. What is happening?

Here is the code:

```
import _Concurrency
import Combine
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var components: [String] = []
    // View Properties
    private let randomTexts = ["re", "ma", "so", "lem", "tap", "do", "rec"]
    // MapKit Properties
    private var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    // Combine Properties
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var publisher = PassthroughSubject<[String], Never>()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // Methods
    @IBAction func tapped() {
        guard let randomText = randomTexts.randomElement() else {
            return
        }
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = randomText
        fillTableView(with: randomText)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchCompleter.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func fillTableView(with randomElement: String) {
        Task {
            let autocompletedComponents = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                publisher
                    .sink { continuation.resume(returning: $0) }
                    .store(in: &cancellables)
            }
            components = autocompletedComponents
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        publisher.send(
            completer.results.map { $0.title }
        )
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return components.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = components[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 15, you can simply use `Publisher.values`, no need to wrap the `Publisher` in a `withCheckedContinuation` block.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I need to target iOS 13 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuation must be resumed exactly once. You are retaining the continuation in the sink closure, and you have a constant publisher value, so the second time you hit the button, a new sink operation is created and the publisher is now sending its results to *two* continuations. You need to make the sink operation happen once only by unsubscribing it when it's done, or by nullifying a local reference to the continuation in the sink (untested example below):

```
let autocompletedComponents = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
    var oneShot = Optional(continuation) 
    publisher
        .sink { 
            oneShot?.resume(returning: $0) 
            oneShot = nil
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

However, apart from learning purposes it's not clear what benefits you're adding by mixing Combine and structured concurrency in this example. Given that the nature of the local search completer is to deliver a continuously updating set of values as the user types, Combine seems like a better fit here. You could wrap the delegate calls with a continuation but you'd have the same problem, you must resume the continuation once and only once which probably means creating brand new delegates for each request.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation! I'll try to improve my code then.

Answer (score 0):

The `withCheckedContinuation` is for emitting a single value. In Swift concurrency, if you want to produce a sequence of results (in this case, one set of results for each update of the `queryFragment`), you would use an `AsyncSequence`. The easiest way is to do that with an `AsyncStream` (or in this case, `AsyncThrowingStream`).

So, for example, assuming you have an asynchronous sequence that emits a value every time your search completer has a set of results. You can just `for await` the sequence, updating the table view when you have new results:

```swift
private var searchCompletionManager = SearchCompleterManager()

func startCompleter() {
    Task { [weak self] in
        guard let results = self?.searchCompletionManager.results else { return }

        for try await completions in results {
            self?.components = completions.map { $0.title }
            self?.tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

So, that begs the question of how you create an `AsyncSequence` for the search results generated by the `MKLocalSearchCompleter`. It could look something like the following, which “yields” values every time the the `MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate` reports new values:

```swift
class SearchCompleterManager: NSObject {
    let searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()

    private var didReceive: (([MKLocalSearchCompletion]) -> Void)?
    private var didFinish: (() -> Void)?
    private var didFail: ((Error) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        searchCompleter.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        didFinish?()
    }

    lazy var results: AsyncThrowingStream<[MKLocalSearchCompletion], Error> = {
        AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
            didReceive = { continuation.yield($0) }
            didFinish  = { continuation.finish() }
            didFail    = { continuation.finish(throwing: $0)}
        }
    }()
}

extension SearchCompleterManager: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        didReceive?(completer.results)
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        didFail?(error)
    }
}
```

And, so, when you update the search text, you would simply update the `queryFragment` of the `MKLocalSearchCompleter` (which will automatically trigger values to be captured by the `for await` loop shown above):

```swift
func search() {
    guard let randomText = randomTexts.randomElement() else {
        return
    }
    searchCompletionManager.searchCompleter.queryFragment = randomText
}
```

---

Needless to say, I am not using Combine at all (I agree with counsel provided elsewhere that one would use async-await or Combine, but not both), but do whatever you want.

But `AsyncSequence` is for types that emit values over time. Just be careful of strong reference cycles, as the compiler does not always warn you of implicit `self` references within the `Task { ... }` block.

For more information about creating your own asynchronous sequences, see WWDC 2021 [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/).